# Count clicks of url in Rails using custom routes.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I try to save summary of clicks on image with link.

In view:

```
#holder
      .hidden-phone
        .banner-left
          - @left_banner.each do |f|
            = link_to image_tag(f.image.url), click_banner_url(f)
        .banner-right
          - @right_banner.each do |f|
            = link_to image_tag(f.image.url), click_banner_url(f)
```

In controller:

```
def click
        @banner = Banner.find(params[:id])
        @banner.update(clicks: @banner.clicks + 1)
        redirect_to @banner.link
end
```

In routes:

```
resources :banners do 
    member do
      get 'click'
    end
end
```

I get error:

NoMethodError in BannersController#click

undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your banner has `nil` for clicks.  Set a default of 0 in your migration - `t.integer :clicks, default: 0`

Comment: @japed I added and checked in schema that clicks is default: 0, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Increment**

Further to making your `default` value `0` in your database, you'll want to use a much more succinct method called [`increment`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment), which will add `1` to your column's value regardless:

> `increment`
>
> Initializes attribute to zero if nil and adds the value passed as by
>   (default is 1). The increment is performed directly on the underlying
>   attribute, no setter is invoked. Only makes sense for number-based
>   attributes. Returns self.

Judging from that, you'll be best doing this:

```
def click
    @banner = Banner.find(params[:id])
    @banner.increment!(:clicks) #-> saves the record
    redirect_to @banner.link
end
```

--

**Filters**

Something else to consider is *how* you're achieving the functionality you want

You mention you're directing people through a "custom route" when they click a banner. This adds an extra level of complexity which doesn't need to be there. You can just use a [filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) in your application:

```
#app/controllers/banners_controller.rb
Class BannersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :click

   def show
      ... logic here
   end

   private

   def click
      @banner = Banner.find params[:id]
      @banner.increment!(:click)
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks now it count clicks, but redirect_to not work. When you click on image on client side nothing is happens, but still count clicks. Banner has link: 'bing.com'.

Comment: You mean to put Class BannersController < ApplicationController => Show => @banner = Banner.find(params[:id]) ?